# Prestashop - Display quantity and features on home featured product

Tags: html, prestashop

I would like to dispay features on home featured product.

On homefeatured.tpl, I've added :

```
<!-- features -->
{foreach from=$products->features item=feature}
    <!-- wine -->
    {if $feature.id_feature eq 7}
        <p class="feature-wine"><a href="{$products->product_link}" title="{$products->name|escape:html:'UTF-8'}">{$feature.value|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a></p>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

But it doesn't work... Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need To Modify homefeatured.php to get this variable from model and pass it to Smarty via Smarty->assign()

Answer (score 0):

The homefeatured module doesn't send these variables to the template.

My advice is to duplicate this module to create yours and add these values.